# How can I restrict my select so that it does not select empty string values?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState() {
        var errors = ModelState
         .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage)
         .Union(x.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.Exception.Message)));
        return errors;
    }
```

It works but when there is an entry for ErrorMessage of "" then it adds this to the list of strings. Is there a way that I could make it only select ErrorMessages if they are not "" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check for the empty string, if it is null or empty discard the select and projection.

```
 protected IEnumerable<string> GetErrorsFromModelState() {
        var errors = ModelState
         .SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Where(error=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage)).Select(error => error.ErrorMessage)
         .Union(x.Value.Errors.Where(error=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage)).Select(error => error.Exception.Message)));
        return errors;
    }
```

Comment: It's giving me an error: Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments  and also: Error 5 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelError' to 'string'

Comment: look at the edited version!, It should be String.IsNullOrEmpty(**error.ErrorMessage**)

Comment: I tried the code and it always produces no results even when there is no error but an exception.

Comment: Why not just add the `.Where()` to the outer query?